# umbraco get content part as xml

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, umbraco

I'm trying to get part of umbraco node content as xml doc. I need to update this part of code from the code behind.
I use the code like this:

```
    Document doc = new Document(1214);
    XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
    umbraco.cms.businesslogic.property.Property items = doc.getProperty("fundItems");
    XmlNode fundsNode = items.ToXml(xmlDoc);
```

The problem is that I get an error:
*Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.*

Not sure if I use ToXml method properly? There seems not to be other solution but I can't find any proper documentation for this method or solutions in the internet.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the XML it's difficult to say what the problem is, but that sounds like it may not be a valid XML document. If it's like many properties I've run across before, it's not stored as a valid XML document (complete with header), but simply the XML data, and thus trying to make a document from it might not work.

I had some trouble trying to access an XML page property. I tried parsing it into a doc like you did and didn't get it right immediately, so I tried something else. What worked for me was to enumerate through the items, as Umbraco recognized them as a collection. It looked something like this:

```
Node node = new Node(1214);
var items = node.GetProperty("fundItems");

foreach (var item in items)
{
    foreach (XElement data in item.BaseElement.Elements("data"))
    {
        if (data.Attribute("alias").Value == "alias1")
        {
            // action for each item
        }
    }
}
```

The XML was formatted like that shown on [this Umbraco project page](http://our.umbraco.org/projects/backoffice-extensions/repeatable-custom-content). I realize your XML and situation may not be analogous to mine, but I hope this helps.